# CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'x' for entity 'x'. Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
class CustomPin : NSManagedObject, MKAnnotation {

    @NSManaged var lat: Double
    @NSManaged var lon: Double
    var title : String? = ""

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
       super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }


    init(coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D , context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CustomPin", in: context)
        super.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        self.lat = coordinate.latitude
        self.lon = coordinate.longitude


    }

    var coordinate  : CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get {
           return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat , longitude: lon)

        }
        set {
            self.lat = newValue.latitude
            self.lon = newValue.longitude
        }
    }
}
```

Above is a class that is meant to be an annotation that can be stored as an NSManagedObject.

When I try to initialize an object of this class with :

```
let pin = CustomPin(coordinate: coordinate, context: moc)
```

I get the following error when setting self.lat = coordinate.latitude:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'CustomPin' for entity 'CustomPin'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

As far as I'm aware you don't use the xcdatamodel when you're making a subclass because you'd just be redeclaring the class?

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I'm aware you don't use the xcdatamodel when you're making a subclass because you'd just be redeclaring the class?

That is incorrect. If you want to use a class with Core Data, the data model must contain a corresponding entity. If not, Core Data doesn't know about it-- and you get this error message.

Core Data may or may not create its own subclass for the entity depending on how you configure the data model. If this class you've created suits your needs, make sure that the data model says to use "manual/none" for subclass generation.